# Missing name tags!

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In my Minecraft, when it updated to 1.7.10, I haven't been able to see player's name tag on the top of their head when I'm playing multiplayer.

Also, when I go to single player, I can't see the name tags for my dogs either! I don't know if it is a glitch or it is in the new update. How do I fix this issue?

Comment: Is not just an option that is now active ?

Comment: Who are these "the name"?

Comment: Is you HUD hidden? Try toggling the HUD by pressing F1.

Answer (score -1):

Try to re-download 1.7.10. Locate your minecraft file (try Run > %appdata% > .minecraft) and go into your versions folder. Delete the folder named 1.7.10. Then just open up the Minecraft Launcher and press play.

Comment: Do you have any citations or evidence about why this might work?

Comment: Well, sometimes, files aren't downloaded by an error.

Comment: What do you mean Jokemaster?